# mysql: set an array to a variable in order to use in "IN" clause

Tags: mysql

I want to set an array to a variable in order to use it in my queries in "IN" clause. The code below gives me an error back, so I am not sure if it is possible in mysql.

```
set @ids = (1,2,3,6);

select 
    sum(promotion_id IN @ids AND confirmed_at IS NOT NULL)
from blabla
```

I get different two differt results. Namely, find_in_set and IN(@ids) give me identical result but it differs from the one I get from IN(1,2,3):

```
set @voda_prom ='1483, 2396, 2395, 1887';

    SUM(FIND_IN_SET(promotion_id,@voda_prom) and confirmed_at IS NOT NULL)*1.0/ SUM(FIND_IN_SET(promotion_id,@voda_prom)) as p,
    SUM(promotion_id IN(1483,2396,2395,1887) and confirmed_at IS NOT NULL)*1.0/ SUM(promotion_id IN(1483,2396,2395,1887)) as p_check,
    SUM(promotion_id IN(@voda_prom) and confirmed_at IS NOT NULL)*1.0/ SUM(promotion_id IN(@voda_prom)) as p_1,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `find_in_set` instead of `in`

```
set @ids = '1,2,3,6';
select 
    SUM(CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(promotion_id,@ids) AND confirmed_at IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from blabla
```

this function is just same as `in_array` in php

Comment: No, it did not. The result is different from when i use IN(1,2,3..)

Comment: you mean its different from `promotion_id in(1,2,3,6)` or just `promotion_id in(@ids)`

Comment: find_in_set and IN(@ids) give me the same results but it is different from IN(1,2,3)

Comment: @let's continue here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129988/mysql-set-an-array-to-a-variable-in-order-to-use-in-in-clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
SET @ids = '1, 2, 3, 6';
select 
    sum(`promotion_id` IN ( @ids)  AND `confirmed_at` IS NOT NULL)
from `blabla`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**You Have To Convert Array Into String First Each Element is Imploaded By , commma**


   $arr=array(1,2,3,6);
     $str_arr=implode(',',$arr);


    set @ids = '1,2,3,6';

    select 
        sum(promotion_id IN @ids AND confirmed_at IS NOT NULL)
    from blabla
```